# Прыжок в Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Я хочу сделать прыжок в Unity3D, но движение у меня реализовано через CharacterController. Когда я добавляю Rigidbody к игроку, то игрока начинает колбасить. Как можно сделать прыжок без Rigidbody, или сделать так, чтобы CharacterController и Rigidbody ладили между собой, и чтобы при этом работал прыжок?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот пример сразу из документации. Используя **[метод Move](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CharacterController.Move.html)** и соответствующую подготовку к ней. `Rigidbody` не нужен.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {

    public float speed = 6.0F;
    public float jumpSpeed = 8.0F;
    public float gravity = 20.0F;
    private Vector3 moveDirection = Vector3.zero;

    void Update() {
        CharacterController controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();

        if (controller.isGrounded) {
            moveDirection = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
            moveDirection = transform.TransformDirection(moveDirection);
            moveDirection *= speed;

            if (Input.GetButton("Jump"))
                moveDirection.y = jumpSpeed;                
        }

        moveDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        controller.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Только не желательно в методе `Update` вызывать `GetComponent` ибо лучше закэшировать и обращаться к методу закэшированного компонента